# Problema na biblioteca Pickle em Python

Tags: python

Então, to tentando aplicar o seguinte código, mas o compilador ta me devolvendo seguinte problema, não consigo pensar em nada que não seja algum problema de instalação, mas obtive esse problema em dois computadores diferentes com o mesmo código:

```
import pickle

arqT = open('turmaAlunos.dat', 'ab')
choice = 'n'


while True:
    nome = input('Digite nome do aluno')
    pickle.dump(nome,arqT)

    if name == '':
        while True:
            choice = input("Voce quer mesmo terminar? [s/n]")
            if choice == 's':
                break
            elif choice == 'n':
                break
            else:
                print("Opção inválida")
                continue

        if choice == 's':
            break
        else:
            continue

    matOk = False
    while not matOk:
        matricula = input('Digite a matricula do aluno:')
        if len(matricula) < 6:
            print('Matricula inválida, digite novamente')
        else:
            matOk = True

    notas = []

    print("Digite as notas do alunos:\n")
    for i in range(3):
        notas.append(int(input()))

    for i in range(len(notas)):
        notas[i] = int(notas[i])

    pickle.dump(notas,arqT)

arqT.close()
```

----Retorno:

```
/usr/bin/python3.6 /../PycharmProjects/aval1/pickle.py
Digite nome do aluno etc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../PycharmProjects/aval1/pickle.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pickle
  File "../PycharmProjects/aval1/pickle.py", line 9, in <module>
    pickle.dump(nome,arqT)
AttributeError: module 'pickle' has no attribute 'dump'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 26,                in <module>
    import cPickle as pickle
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cPickle'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in        apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in     <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in     <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in     <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 36,     in <module>
    import pickle
  File "../PycharmProjects/aval1/pickle.py", line 9, in <module>
    pickle.dump(nome,arqT)
AttributeError: module 'pickle' has no attribute 'dump'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../PycharmProjects/aval1/pickle.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pickle
  File "../PycharmProjects/aval1/pickle.py", line 9, in <module>
    pickle.dump(nome,arqT)
AttributeError: module 'pickle' has no attribute 'dump'
```

----att

continuo com o problema no codigo:
    import pickle

```
arq = open('testePickle.dat','wb')

variavel = 0

pickle.dump(variavel,arq)
```

Comment: observação: uso linux

Comment: como você instalou esse Python3? Isso não é pra acontecer.

Comment: na verdade, parece que você tem arquivos .py do Python2 em cima das libs do seu Python3 - você pode ter detruido suas instalações de Python (no sentido de ficarem inusáveis) se em algum momento usou "sudo pip install" - nesse caso o "pip" instala arquivos dele por cima dos arquivos do Python do sistema, e pode acontecer mistura de versões.

Comment: nunca cheguei a instalar python2 nessa distro que to usando, e só usei o pip na tentativa de concertar esse problema, sequer tinha o pip instalado antes

Answer (score 1):

Seu problema está no nome do seu arquivo. Você chamou ele de `pickle.py` porém `pickle` já e um nome de módulo que vem com o python, logo, está ficando confuso o que você quer dizer com `import pickle`.

Renomeie seu programa de `pickle.py` para `test_pickle.py`. Além disso remova o arquivo `pickle.pyc` que foi gerado na mesma pasta. Isso vai corrigir o seu problema.

Answer (score -1):

Aparentemente você quebrou sua instalação do sistema de Python3 - e possivelmente a de Python2.

Todos os Linux mdoernos permitem - se já não vem por padrão - a instalação paralela do Python 2.7 e uma versão recente do Python 3. Tentar interferir nessas instalações por fora do gerenciamento de pacotes da sua distribuição Linux, mesmo que seja com o uso de "pip install" - o gerenciador de pacotes do próprio Python - pode ter efeitos destrutivos.

A instalação de repositórios não oficiais com versões diferentes de software (por exemplo, um repositório não oficial como os que são chamados de "PPA"), por vezes pode causar mais problemas do que benefícios - já que a integração dos pacotes nesses repositórios com o restante do sistema não tem a curadoria dos autores da distribuição - em geral contém só o que "funciona para o autor do repositório")

`pickle` é um dos módulos fundamentais da biblioteca padrão do Python - e os erros que você tem mostram que não pode ser carregado - e por uma questão complexa (cpickle só existe no Python 2, e você tem uma mensagem de erro de que o "cPickle não existe" num módulo que está numa pasta de Python 3).

O que você tem que tentar fazer aí é restaurar as instalações de python2 E de Python3 para as originais da sua distribuição Linux - e lembrar de nunca tentar instalar nada lá exceto pelo gerenciador de pacotes do sistema. Para instalar outras versões do Python, de preferência por compila-las você mesmo, em um prefixo diferente, e para qualquer projeto de Python, crie um "virtualenv" que pode conter versões personalidas de todas as bibliotecas terceiras que o projeto usa de forma isolada. (Nunca use "sudo pip install" para instalar ou atualizar um pacote dos Python do sistema).

Comment: Valeu, minha distro linux veio zerada de apps, instalei tudo manualmente, mas vou fazer o que você instruiu